# Access Indirect property from XAML - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I have a Control class named **MyControl** and it has direct bool property **AccessDirectProperty** and an Object **MyControlSettings**

```
    public class MyControl : Control
    {
        public bool AccessDirectProperty
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public MyControlSettings ControlSettings
        {
            get;set;
        }
    }
```

Please find the **MyControlSettings** class details

```
public class MyControlSettings
{
    public bool AccessIndirectProperty
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

Direct property **AccessDirectProperty** can be accessible from XAML without any error.

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <local:MyControl AccessDirectProperty="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But I cannot access the property **AccessIndirectProperty** from the object **ControlSettings** in XAML. The below code fails to do that.

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <local:MyControl AccessDirectProperty="True" ControlSettings.AccessIndirectProperty=""/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Because `ControlSettings.AccessIndirectProperty` is not a property/member of `MyControl`...

Comment: Side note: If you intend to bind against some of the properties of `MyControl` -- with those properties being the binding target --, you would need to make those properties DependencyProperties...

Comment: Yes, I need to set the AccessIndirectProperty in XAML. Is there any way to achieve it using the ControlSettings which is a property of MyControl?

Comment: Can you please provide me an example of using DependencyProperties to achieve my requirement mentioned above?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve, so i can't tell you what you should do. But perhaps you could make `ControlSettings.AccessIndirectProperty` an attached property through which the state of MyControl and its associated MyControlSettings instance could be manipulated. Or perhaps you could create a whole MyControlSettings instance in XAML and set this like `<MyControl><ControlSettings><MyControlSettings SomeProperty="true"/></ControlSettings></MyControl>` Note that this creates and assigns a new MyControlSettings object, it does not modfiy an existing MyControlSettings object

Comment: With regard to DependencyProperties: There are many guides/blog posts/documentation and even questions and answers related to DP here on StackOverflow. It shouldn't take much time to find a lot of information and examples through a quick Google search...

Comment: By the way, my side note about DependencyProperties was not about your problem, hence me declaring it a side note. It was about the possibility that you might want to bind against those properties of your control (similar to what you would do with other bindable properties of standard WPF controls), in which case just having an ordinary property is not sufficient...

Comment: <MyControl><ControlSettings><MyControlSettings SomeProperty="true"/></ControlSettings></MyControl>. This one worked for my case. Thank you

Comment: @elgonzo: Since you comment solved the OP's problem, I suggest that you turn you comment into an answer, so that future readers can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, on a technical level, the following is not useful to modify a property of an existing *MyControlSettings* instance provided through *MyControl.ControlSettings*. However, if your use case allows creating and assigning an entirely new *MyControlSettings* instance to *MyControl.ControlSettings*, you can do so in XAML:

```
<local:MyControl>
    <ControlSettings>
        <local:MyControlSettings AccessIndirectProperty="true" />
    </ControlSettings>
</local:MyControl>
```

A side note: The term "*ControlSettings*" suggest to me that you want to kind of "package" control settings/properties in some kind of *MyControlSettings* "container". Now, i don't know why and what the motivation for this is, but keep in mind that choosing this approach can make it very hard or even impossible to use data bindings in a meaningful way where such a settings property is supposed to be the binding target. If you want to be able to use individual settings as binding target (like `AccessIndirectProperty="{Binding Path=Source}"`), i would rather suggest your *MyControl* exposes those settings individually as [DependencyProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties).

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that XAML does not support accessing "nested" properties.

You could, however, make `ControlSettings` an independent class with [attached properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview):

```
public class ControlSettings : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AccessIndirectPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
              "AccessIndirectProperty", typeof(bool), typeof(ControlSettings),
              new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public static bool GetAccessIndirectProperty(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool) d.GetValue(AccessIndirectPropertyProperty);
    }
    public static void SetAccessIndirectProperty(DependencyObject d, bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue(AccessIndirectPropertyProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Then,

```
<local:MyControl x:Name="myControl" 
                 AccessDirectProperty="True" 
                 ControlSettings.AccessIndirectProperty="True" />
```

would set a value which could be accessed via

```
var p = ControlSettings.GetAccessIndirectProperty(myControl); // yields True
```